# Display Form input in additional Text field

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to have a contract filled in with values from a form on the same page, I have the basic idea but can not understand what I am missing in my application of it.

```
jQuery(function($) {
var input_5 = $('#input_5');
var Child2Name = $('#Child2Name');
var previewinput_5 = $('.Previewinput_5');
var preview2ChildName = $('.PreviewChild2Name');

input_5.keyup(function(e) {
    previewChild1Name.text(input_5.val()); });


Child2Name.keyup(function(e) {
    preview2ChildName.text(Child2Name.val());  });
     });




<li class="form-line" id="id_5">
    <label class="form-label-left" id="label_5" for="input_5">
      Legal Business Name<span class="form-required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div id="cid_5" class="form-input">
      <input type="text" class=" form-textbox validate[required]" 
data-type="input- textbox" id="input_5" name="q5_legalBusiness"
size="20" value="" />
    </div>
  </li>

<input type="text" name="child2name" id="Child2Name" /> 
<Label>Child2 Name</label>


Whether it’s what <span class="input_5"></span> <br>
Whether it’s what <span class="PreviewChild2Name"></span> <BR>
```

The second part works fine, the first is clearly having issues with how the actual form is being displayed

http://jsfiddle.net/3dMqU/10/

Comment: Can you be more clear about what isn't working?

Comment: The text only displays for class="PreviewChild2Name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the right names(variable name and class name) in these lines:

```
var previewinput_5 = $('.Previewinput_5');
Whether it’s what <span class="cid_5"></span>
```

I assume `previewinput_5` should be `previewChild1Name` and `Previewinput_5` should be `cid_5`.  Your `fiddle` worked for me because you did the naming in it correctly, which is why I was confused.

Comment: The Fiddle only work for the second one, not for the first, that is my confusion, which I added to by mis-labeling my code on here

Comment: You have them mislabeled. Change this line ` var previewinput_5 = $('.Previewinput_5');` to  `var previewChild1Name = $('.input_5');` and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Nice, It works on my fiddle, not on my project yet, but at least it is one item down, thank you!